# Selenium webdriver issue with version

Tags: java, scala, selenium

I am trying to write a script that fetches Estonian zip codes. Here is the code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion
import org.openqa.selenium.{By, WebDriver}
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver

object Application {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val  driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME)
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
    query(driver, "Pelguranna 9")
  }

  def query(driver: WebDriver, query: String) {
    driver.get("https://www.omniva.ee/eng")

    val tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='search-tabs']/li[1]"))
    tab.click()

    val name = driver.findElement(By.name("zip_address"))
    name.sendKeys(query)
    name.submit()

    val result = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='zip_container']/p[0]"))
    print(result)
  }

}
```

Basically, you should go to URL, click on 'FIND A ZIP CODE' tab, insert address, press enter and take first result.

But I am getting an error:

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.verifyCanInteractWithElement(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:282)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.sendKeys(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:326)
    at Application$.query(grab.scala:20)
    at Application$.main(grab.scala:10)
    at Application.main(grab.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I have never written anything like this before, so do not know what this error means. Can anyone say what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Not sure if this an issue with html unit driver. However, even though emulating real browser is possible it is not [recommended](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver#Emulating_a_Specific_Browser). So probably try chromedriver instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following issues with your code.

1. The XPaths for elements are wrong.
2. There is not enough wait time between operations.

I am a JAVA guy and was able to get the zip code using the following code. I believe you can make the changes to python.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    ((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    test(driver, "Pelguranna 9");
}

public static void test(WebDriver driver, String query) throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("https://www.omniva.ee/eng");

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Find a ZIP code'][@href='#search-zip']"));
    tab.click();

    WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.name("zip_address"));
    name.sendKeys(query);
    name.submit();

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='zip_container']/p/span"));
    System.out.println(result.getText());
}
```

Hope this helps you.